# Cannot set Android Studio environment variables

Tags: android-studio

To avoid installing SDKs on my C: drive which is already low on space, I search a little bit and understand that I have to change SDK installation location through environment variables.

So I find them from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) and:

- Create `ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\Sdk\` as a `User` variable
- Create `ANDROID_USER_HOME=D:\Android\Sdk\` as a `User` variable
- Add `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_USER_HOME` to `Path`
- Run `set` command in the terminal to make sure everything is set properly
- Download Android Studio and start the installation

Then this is what I see:

[image]

`Android SDK Location` still points to my `C:` drive.

So I quit the installer and this time set both `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_USER_HOME` as `SYSTEM` variables. Same result.

```
C:\Users\omids>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\Sdk\
ANDROID_USER_HOME=D:\Android\Sdk\
APPDATA=C:\Users\omids\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-P8G5R28
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\omids
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-P8G5R28
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OneDrive=C:\Users\omids\OneDrive
OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\omids\OneDrive
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\;C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\;C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\bin;D:\Android\Sdk\;D:\Android\Sdk\;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=5e03
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\omids\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-P8G5R28
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-P8G5R28
USERNAME=omids
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\omids
windir=C:\WINDOWS
ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN=1
```

I know I can change that path manually and proceed with installation, but if Android Studio cannot read those variables or ignores them I'm sure I'll have issues down the road.